# java client server application bug

Tags: java, sockets, input, client

i am writeing a client server application with sockets in java.
both the client and the server sits on my computer.
the goal is to send messages from the client to the sever.
i think my sockets are ok, but something is wrong with my way of getting the messages.
also for some reason the server and the client somethimes get "stuck" when i click
connect or start server.

here is the client code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JFrame{
private int connected = 0;
private JTextArea txt;
private JTextField mText;
private JButton sendMessage;
private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JButton connect;
private JButton disconnect;
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private PrintWriter out;
public Client(){
    setLayout(null);

    txt = new JTextArea();
    scroll = new JScrollPane(txt);
    scroll.setBounds(25,10,325,200);
    add(scroll);


    mText = new JTextField();
    mText.setBounds(25,220,250,30);
    add(mText);

    sendMessage=new JButton("Send");
    sendMessage.setBounds(280,220,70,30);   
    add(sendMessage);

    connect= new JButton("Connect");
    connect.setBounds(25,260,100,30);
    add(connect);

    disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    disconnect.setBounds(135,260,100,30);
    add(disconnect);
  //events stuff
       eventHandler handler = new eventHandler();
       sendMessage.addActionListener(handler);
       connect.addActionListener(handler);
       disconnect.addActionListener(handler);
   }
public class eventHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==sendMessage){
            sendMessage();
        }
        else
            if(e.getSource()==connect){
            if(connected==0){
            try{
             connect();
             connected = 1;
             }catch(Exception e1){
                 e1.printStackTrace();
                 System.out.print(e1);
             }
            }else
                printOnScreen("you are already connected...");
          }
        else
            if(e.getSource()==disconnect){
                if(connected==1){
                 try{
                    disconnect();
                    connected = 0;
                 }catch(Exception e1){
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                     System.out.print(e1);
                 }
                 }else{printOnScreen("you are not connected");} 
             }
  }
}


public void printOnScreen(String m){
    txt.append("\n"+m);
}

public void sendMessage(){
    String message = txt.getText();
    out.print(message);
}
public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    socket=new Socket("localhost",6789);
    input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    output= new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
    out.print("client connecting");
    out.flush();
}
public void disconnect() throws IOException{
    out.print("Client disconnecting");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    input.close();
    output.close();
    socket.close();
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    Client cFrame = new Client();
    cFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    cFrame.setSize(385,350);
    cFrame.setTitle("             ---___Client1___---");
    cFrame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

And the server code:

```
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.EventHandler;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Server extends JFrame {
private int running =0;

private JPanel showInformation;
private JButton start;
private JButton stop;
private JTextArea infoArea;
private JScrollPane scroll;

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket client;   

private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

private PrintWriter out;

public Server(){
   //setting looks of Frame
   setLayout(null);
   showInformation=new JPanel();
   start = new JButton("Start Server");
   stop=new JButton("Stop Server");
   infoArea= new JTextArea(20,27);
   infoArea.setEnabled(false);
   infoArea.setEditable(false);
   scroll = new JScrollPane(infoArea);
   scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
   scroll.setBounds(25,10,325,200);
   scroll.setEnabled(true);
   add(scroll);

   showInformation.setSize(300, 200);
   showInformation.setBounds(25,5,325,200);
   add(showInformation);
   infoArea.setLineWrap(true);
   start.setBounds(25,225,150,50);
   stop.setBounds(200,225,150,50);

   add(start);
   add(stop);     
   //events stuff
   eventHandler handler = new eventHandler();
   start.addActionListener(handler);
   stop.addActionListener(handler);

   //sockets 
}

public void printOnScreen(String m){
    infoArea.append("\n"+m);
}

public class eventHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==start){
              if(running==1)
                  printOnScreen("Server Already Running !!!");
              else
              {
                  try{
                       startServer();
                  }catch(Exception e1){
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                      System.out.print(e1);
                  }
                  running=1;

              }
           }
        else 
          if(e.getSource()==stop){
              if(running==0)
                  printOnScreen("Server Not Running !!!");
              else
              {
                  try{
                      stopServer();
                  }catch(Exception e1){
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                      System.out.print(e1);
                  }
                  running=0;
             }
    }

}
}

public void startServer() throws IOException{
    server = new ServerSocket(6789);
    running=1;
    Listener ls = new  Listener();
    ls.run();
    client =  server.accept();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
    out.flush();
    printOnScreen("Server Started !!!");
    printOnScreen("waiting for connection...");
}

public void stopServer() throws IOException{
  output.writeObject("Server Stoped");
  output.flush();
  input.close();
  output.close();
  client.close();
  server.close();
  printOnScreen("Server Stopped");
}


public void getMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
try{
    String message = (String)input.readObject();
    printOnScreen("client: "+message);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

class Listener extends Thread{
    public Listener(){

    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            client = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(e1);
        }
        while(running==1){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                getMessage();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.print(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.print(e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args){
   Server s = new Server();
   s.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   s.setSize(385, 350);
   s.setVisible(true);
   s.setTitle("      ----Server----");
   s.setTitle("Server Manager");
 }

}
```

here is the eror code:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at Server.getMessage(Server.java:129)
at Server$Listener.run(Server.java:152)
at Server.startServer(Server.java:105)
at Server$eventHandler.actionPerformed(Server.java:73)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: describe "stuck" and "sometimes".  Do the processes crash, hang, just get very slow, consume all the memory or CPU on the system?  Every 3rd run, or maybe every time the time is exactly on an hour?  If you attach with a debugger, where do the processes stick?

Comment: Is this a problem in your Swing (UI) code or your IPC (client-server) code?

Comment: stuck is the button get like pressed but not released and 
the all JFrame is not responding
like the program crushed or is waiting for something

this is the eror: 
  
it happens every time.

Comment: I bet you are doing blocking network operations like server.accept() on the EDT. And you try to access `input` before it has been set up. That's why it's still null sometimes. And that happens only sometimes, because you created a classic racing condition.

Comment: so how do i solve it?

Comment: i want to make it so that
even if there is no connection yet or no message
that it will just pass on and try again until there is a message
like just wait for a message and then continue
how do i do that?

Comment: That's very broad. First of all try to clean up the code a little bit. Split GUI from your business logic.

Comment: As Fildor already described, you are handling the server on the EDT Thread. Normal ServerSocket pattern is to run it on a new Thread. In your case, I would let the whole ServerSocket part run on a different Thread that you can control from your GUI. Aditionally, each clientSocket should be treated in a different Thread, so you can support multiple clients. I also noticed that you try to close all your resources in a row catching only one exception. If you get an exception on one of the first lines, the remaining resources cannot be closed, would check that out too.

Comment: thank you very much
i think i kind of understood what you mean
will you be able to repair my code according to your coment?